# Pendrive is not working after installing ubuntu 13.04 64 BIT on it. Help?

Tags: installation, 13.04, 64-bit, usb-drive, disk-management

I've installed ubuntu 13.04 64 bit on my hp v115w 8 gb pendrive. I mean the full installation, not the liveDisk one. Now the pendrive is completely dead. It booted from the pendrive couple of times last night. But after that today the computer is not even detecting the hardware.I've tried other computers but no computer shows any response when the drive is plugged in. I saw device manager, disk manager.. nowhere the drive is being detected! I know there is not any hardware failure! I need some urgent help!! please. Thank you!

Comment: in a terminal, type `tail -f /var/log/kern.log` then plug your drive. Do you see any messages ?

Answer (score 0):

try installing https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gnome-disk-utility/

A Disk utility tool. And see if it helps!